# LAZADA Open platform - Invalid authorization code

Tags: php, sdk

I have trouble to connect seller account to lazada open platform
I add callback to mywebsite/callbackurl

```
$c = new LazopClient($this->LazURL, $this->appKey, $this->appSecret);
$request = new LazopRequest('/auth/token/create');

$request->addApiParam('code',$code);
dd($c->execute($request));
```

It returned to mywebsite/callbackurl?code=xxxxxx with error ISP "Invalid authorization code"

"{"code":"InvalidCode","type":"ISP","message":"Invalid authorization code","request_id":"21223b8216267097993104138"}"

Hope someone can help me regarding the issue

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The thread is old but I hope this will help in some kind. I chased Lazada people for almost one month to get the APIs working for getting conversions. Their OPEN SDKs won't work at all. So you need to use the API call method to get the data from the absence account. Below is the full PHP code that I'm using to get the data from their Open API.

TO get credentials details, Navigate to Lazada absence Account -> Integration -> OPEN API

```
<?php
$app_id = LiteApp Key;
$secret = LiteApp Secret;
$user_token = User Token;

function hmac_sha256($data, $key){
    return hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $key);
}
function msectime() {
   list($msec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
   return $sec . '000';
}
$timeStamp = msectime();

function generateSign($apiName,$params,$secret)
{
    ksort($params);

    $stringToBeSigned = '';
    $stringToBeSigned .= $apiName;
    foreach ($params as $k => $v)
    {
        $stringToBeSigned .= "$k$v";
    }
    unset($k, $v);
    return strtoupper(hmac_sha256($stringToBeSigned,$secret));
}

$options = array(
                'app_key' => $app_id,
                'timestamp' => $timeStamp,
                'sign_method' =>'sha256',
                'userToken'=> $user_token,
                'dateStart'=> '2021-11-01',
                'dateEnd'=> '2021-11-15',
                'offerId'=> OFFER ID, #You can get this from conversion report.
                'limit' => 10,
                'page' => 1,
            );

$signature = generateSign('/marketing/conversion/report',$options,$secret);
$url = "https://api.lazada.co.th/rest/marketing/conversion/report";
#List of available endpoint - https://open.lazada.com/doc/doc.htm?spm=affiliate.home.0.0.5b81623b6bdk7G#?docId=108065&nodeId=10443
$i=0;
foreach ($options as $key => $value)
{
    if($i == 0){
        $url .= "?" ."$key=" . urlencode($value);
    }else{
        $url .= "&" ."$key=" . urlencode($value);
    }
    $i++;   
}
$url.= '&sign='.$signature;


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use Lazada npm package [Lazada-open-platform-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazada-open-platform-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Check the value you are using for $this->LazURL

You're probably using the country specific api endpoint such as api.lazada.sg, however for the /auth api you have to use the global api.lazada.com endpoint.